# How to include OpenMVG library in my program?

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have OpenMVG library installed on my laptop. I have to extend it and use some of its functions of its CPP files in my C++ program. How can I go about it? I was trying to use `cmake` but not getting exactly how to proceed and what commands to use?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Are you able to include header files? Can you build the project?

Comment: I have built the OpenMVG pipeline and can run any of its executable already there in library. Now I am writing a program and want to use some of its functions which are there in its CPP and header files. So, I have placed my program in the directory where all other main CPP files of the library were present and trying to make changes in CMakeLists.txt but in vain.

Comment: I would expect a linker error in your case. Therefore I would suggest you to specify target link libraries. You can take a look how it is done in examples from openMVG github (https://github.com/openMVG/openMVG/tree/master/src/openMVG_Samples/undisto_Brown).